# Magento Color Swatches Shows error when hover

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

When I hover on any swatches on product view page it gives error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: PointerManager is not defined`

I used magento 1.9.1 and create configurable product with by-default in-built functionality of color and size swatches. It shows me error when hover but when click on any of swatch its working perfect.

Only issue with hover.

Any one please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you're not using Safari on iOS. What I did to stop this error from popping up is adding:

```
typeof PointerManager != "undefined" &&
```

to lines 483 and 540 of swatches-product.js just inside the if statement.

This will check if PointerManager even exists before trying to do something with it.